# Creating own logger function

Tags: node.js, filesystems

I am learning Node.js and its file system and I have a task to create own custom logger function.

```
myLogger('aaa')
myLogger('bbb')
myLogger('ccc')
myLogger('ddd')
myLogger('eee')
myLogger('fff')
myLogger('ggg')
myLogger('hhh')
myLogger('iii')
myLogger('jjj')
myLogger('kkk')
myLogger('lll')
```

Should create file with all the parameters logged in the file. The file should always contain maximum 10 lines (10 logged messages). But the problem I mainly have is, that my function logs alwys only the last logger call - in this case "lll". I printed out to the console time of opening txt file and time of closing file. For all calls it is same opening time and same closing time. So that's why the ouput is always the last one call.

But I have no idea how to solve it.

```
function myLogger(stringToLog) {
  var today = new Date();
  var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  console.log(stringToLog, "start", time)
    return fs.readFile(myLogPath, {})
    .then(data => {
      let dataInArray = String(data).split("\n");
      if(dataInArray.length > 9) {
        dataInArray.splice(0, dataInArray.length - 9);
      }
      dataInArray.push(stringToLog);
        fs.writeFile(myLogPath, dataInArray.join("\n"))
      var today = new Date();
      var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
      console.log(stringToLog, "end", time)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are return a Promise in the `myLogger()` function.

In this case you should use `async/await` things in your code.

```
async function myLogger() { ... }

await myLogger('aaa');
await myLogger('bbb');
```

Comment: I am afraid that is not the solution. I gives me error "await is only valid in async function" ...